# Removing "category" from URLs then "add_endpoint()" won't work…

Tags: url-rewriting, slug, endpoints

For example, the original URL would be `http://localhost/category/sub_category/`.

What I want is `http://localhost/sub_category/`, furthermore, I want to add an endpoint to the URL which looks like `http://localhost/sub_category/endpoint/`.

I've removed the "category" from the URL successfully by following this tutorial https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-remove-category-from-your-urls-in-wordpress/ .

But once I remove the "category" from the url, the `add_rewrite_endpoint( 'endpoint', EP_CATEGORIES )` won't work…